# Android Relative Layout can't make image on center

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hi i manage to make the icon center same line with the text in linear view, but I wanna add in a arrow image at the right side so i have to switch to relative view. As shown in the image, I can't manage to set the relative view left icon look like linear view.

**EDIT**
I want to arrow icon stay on the right.

[image]

Left image is linear, right is relative.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layercontainer"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/categoryIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/categoryIcon"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nextIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am sorry i did not make a clear explanation.
I want the arrow to stay at right side at the same time hope the align is still look the same in linear layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using the TextView properties [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) and drawableRight

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/whatever"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
android:width="fill_parent"
```

That way and setting the TextView's gravity to center, everything should be ok

Also, using a single TextView instead of a RelativeLayout + 3 views is a big improvement in simplicity. Anyway, if you were to stick to 3 views, using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout is a good advice.

Comment: Try to make the witdh of TextView "fill_parent". Then you may need to set the gravity to left|center_vertical for the text to stay at the left. If this doesn't work, don't go crazy and stick to linearlayout + TextView (icon + text) + ImageView (arrow). There's an attribute drawablePadding, but it can cause you some headache.

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:drawableRight="@drawable/next"` works.
Thanks alot Maragues !

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use a LinearLayout?

Seems like this would work:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/layercontainer" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="10dp"> 
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/categoryIcon" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" /> 
    <TextView android:id="@+id/categoryTitle" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" /> 
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/nextIcon" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the last imageview to `android:layout_width="0dp"` and then add `android:layout_weight="1"` to make it take all the remaining space after the first two are placed and then `android:layout_gravity="right"`, which will make the widget align to the right side of the view space alloted.  That should give you the look you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You should user LinearLayout for a simple xml structure

Because `The LinearLayout is the most simple layout available in Android. A LinearLayout organizes layout components in a linear fashion horizontally or vertically`

[Creating Efficient Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html) says about performance of RelativeLayout and LinearLayout: