# Need the image to be right aligned and centered

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

[Show the list as clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791319/show-the-list-as-clickable)

From the above post I am able to have the image shown but it only appears on the first line of the title text. I would like it to be centre aligned if the title is 2 or more lines long.

What setting in android Imageview would let me do this?

Comment: put layout code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code it will show image in the center

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:layout_gravity="center"
 >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:gravity="center"

     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075475/android-relative-layout-cant-make-image-on-center